# SQLite 3 not releasing memory in Golang

Tags: sqlite, memory, memory-leaks, go, out-of-memory

I'm having issues getting Go to play nicely with SQLite. I fixed it in the past without problems but it has been some time and I can't remember what I did to get it to work properly. I'm using the [`mattn/go-sqlite3`](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3) package to process and insert a lot of data into an SQLite database but somehow Go always ends up eating all my RAM until it finally exits with an error status code. Just to make sure I had isolated the memory starvation problem to SQLite I wrote the following simple program to test it:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./test.db"); if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }; defer db.Close()

    ddl := `
        PRAGMA automatic_index = ON;
        PRAGMA cache_size = 32768;
        PRAGMA cache_spill = OFF;
        PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
        PRAGMA journal_size_limit = 67110000;
        PRAGMA locking_mode = NORMAL;
        PRAGMA page_size = 4096;
        PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;
        PRAGMA secure_delete = ON;
        PRAGMA synchronous = NORMAL;
        PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;
        PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
        PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 16384;

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
            "id" TEXT,
            "username" TEXT,
            "password" TEXT
        );

        CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "id" ON "user" ("id");
    `

    _, err = db.Exec(ddl); if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    queries := map[string]*sql.Stmt{}

    queries["user"], _ = db.Prepare(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "user" VALUES (?, ?, ?);`); if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }; defer queries["user"].Close()

    tx, err := db.Begin(); if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
        user := map[string]string{
            "id": string(i),
            "username": "foo",
            "password": "bar",
        }

        _, err := tx.Stmt(queries["user"]).Exec(user["id"], user["username"], user["password"]); if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if i % 32768 == 0 {
            tx.Commit()
            db.Exec(`PRAGMA shrink_memory;`)

            tx, err = db.Begin(); if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }

    tx.Commit()
}
```

When I run the above code, Go eats more than 100 MiB of memory every second without every releasing any, and after a minute or so, it ends up consuming 6/7 GiB and then the process gets killed. I've tried variations with and without defining the SQLite PRAGMAs but with no luck.

According to the defined PRAGMAs, SQLite should never use more than 128 MiB of RAM.

Have I made any mistake or is there something wrong with either mattn/go-sqlite3 or Go GC?

---

Profiling with `davecheney/profile` as per [these instructions](https://medium.com/code-adventures/profiling-golang-851db2d9ae24) yields this not so helpful output:

```
alix@900X4C:~/Go/src$ go tool pprof --text ./test /tmp/profile102098478/mem.pprof
Adjusting heap profiles for 1-in-4096 sampling rate
Total: 0.0 MB
     0.0 100.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% runtime.allocm
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% database/sql.(*DB).Exec
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% database/sql.(*DB).conn
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% database/sql.(*DB).exec
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteDriver).Open
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3._Cfunc_sqlite3_threadsafe
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% main.main
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% runtime.cgocall
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% runtime.gosched0
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% runtime.main
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% runtime.newextram
```

This was just for 1000000 iterations and memory still grows like there's no tomorow.

I also tried the same code on two MacBook Pros, both running the latest version of Go from brew (1.3.1), in one of them the memory usage topped 10 GiB and the other averaged 2 GiB of RAM consumption. This looks like an odd behavior, what can I do to trace down the discrepancies and fix the memory hogging?

Comment: Running go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64.

Comment: Can you humour me and remove the `user` map? Just pass in the values and see how much that changes your memory usage?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Just did, can't say it's any different - on iteration 1081344 memory usage was reaching 5 GiB already.

Comment: I can't reproduce the memory growth, mind sharing your measurements?

Profiling also says nothing.

Comment: @AntoineG: I've added some pprof output, but I don't think it's very intelligible.

Comment: Same problem here, go-sqlite3 not releasing the memory. Did you already got a solution?

Comment: For the reference: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/157

Comment: @fls0815: No, I still need to try the bleeding edge version of Go but I'm also inclined to think this is related to the SQLite package itself and not Go.

Comment: @fls0815: I posted a solution in my answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: @peterSO what do you mean by a solution? It still eats all the memory I have.

Comment: @AlixAxel: I provided a solution that solved the problem for me and invited you to try it. Do you have the problem when you run using [Go 1.4 Beta 1](http://golang.org/dl/#go1.4beta1): `go version go1.4beta1 linux/amd64`?

Comment: @peterSO: I did not (due to lack of time) but I highly doubt that's the cause - and I think I would be quite disappointed with Go if that was the case.

Comment: I've add one line to fix this.

Could you please test this?

Comment: @mattn: Just updated and tried it, 1M inserts are still consuming well over 1 GiB of RAM.

Comment: @AlixAxel Did you try with this commit? https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/commit/e63d2546a03e8591c61871c4e494587cc28bdd79

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `go-sqlite3` package has been fixed:

https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/commit/e63d2546a03e8591c61871c4e494587cc28bdd79

Answer (score 6):

I'm unable to reproduce your results. It uses about 100 MiB of memory.

```
$ go version
go version devel +7ab3adc146c9 Sun Oct 19 10:33:50 2014 -0700 linux/amd64
$ sqlite3 --version
3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30 27392118af4c38c5203a04b8013e1afdb1cebd0d
$ go get -v github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 (download)
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
$ go run simple.go
0
32768
65536
<SNIP>
9928704
9961472
9994240
$
```

A runtime.MemStats records statistics about the Go memory allocator. It does not include memory managed by SQLite. For example, at the end of the program,

```
var ms runtime.MemStats
runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms)
fmt.Println(
    ms.Alloc,      // bytes allocated and still in use
    ms.TotalAlloc, // bytes allocated (even if freed)
    ms.Sys,        // bytes obtained from system (sum of XxxSys below)
    ms.Mallocs,    // number of mallocs
    ms.Frees,      // number of frees
)
```

Output:

```
12161440 7953059928 18757880 160014535 159826250
```

And it also works on [Go 1.4 Beta 1](http://golang.org/dl/#go1.4beta1)

```
$ go version
go version go1.4beta1 linux/amd64
```

Comment: I just ran the same code on my Mac work laptop (my original test was under Ubuntu 14.04) and memory usage also went from 4.5GiB to over 14GiB before the process finally finished. I'm running Go 1.3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the try-out BTW, at least on your end the code behaves like it should. Now I just need to figure out why.

Comment: @AlixAxel: What results do you get from `runtime.MemStats`? See my revised answer for my results.

Comment: This is what I get from MemStats at the end of the code: `440344 7793418088 4065528 160624992 160620181`. Seems like very little memory was used, but by watching htop I can tell that nearly 12 GiB were used by the Go process during most of the time. I'll try the same thing on my other laptop later today.

Comment: @AlixAxel: What results do you get if you run using `go version devel +7ab3adc146c9` or later?

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed on GitHub at length. I'm posting here to help

https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/157

Solution was found, issue had to do with this statement:

```
_, err := tx.Stmt(queries["user"]).Exec(user["id"], user["username"], user["password"]);
```

this is throwing away the rows and the code following never calls Close().

This version of the test program works correctly

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./test.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    ddl := `
        PRAGMA automatic_index = ON;
        PRAGMA cache_size = 32768;
        PRAGMA cache_spill = OFF;
        PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
        PRAGMA journal_size_limit = 67110000;
        PRAGMA locking_mode = NORMAL;
        PRAGMA page_size = 4096;
        PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;
        PRAGMA secure_delete = ON;
        PRAGMA synchronous = NORMAL;
        PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;
        PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
        PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 16384;

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
            "id" TEXT,
            "username" TEXT,
            "password" TEXT
        );

        CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "id" ON "user" ("id");
    `

    _, err = db.Exec(ddl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    queries := map[string]*sql.Stmt{}

    queries["user"], _ = db.Prepare(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "user" VALUES (?, ?, ?);`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer queries["user"].Close()

    tx, err := db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
        user := map[string]string{
            "id":       string(i),
            "username": "foo",
            "password": "bar",
        }

        rows, err := tx.Stmt(queries["user"]).Exec(user["id"], user["username"], user["password"])
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        // CLOSE ROWS HERE!
        rows.Close()

        if i%32768 == 0 {
            tx.Commit()
            db.Exec(`PRAGMA shrink_memory;`)

            tx, err = db.Begin()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }

    tx.Commit()
}
```

Comment: This would solve the leak indeed, but it's no longer necessary as the package as been fixed to account for ignored variables. I'm still curious to know why some users couldn't reproduce the problem thought. Thanks for sharing on StackOverflow.

Comment: Note that this proposed solution does not work. `rows` will be a [`SQLiteResult`](http://godoc.org/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3#SQLiteResult) and not `SQLiteRows` - `SQLiteResult` doesn't have a `Close` method: *rows.Close undefined (type sql.Result has no field or method Close)*.